# change the axis Y. From "bottom left" to "top left"? (opengl)

Tags: opengl, coordinates, coordinate-systems

change the axis Y. From "bottom left" to "top left"?
Tried glScalef (1.f,-1.f, 1.f);
But it turns everything upside down.
How to make a
glRectf (0,0,200,200);
draw in the upper left corner instead of the bottom left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

- `width` and `height` of the viewport,
- and an "corresponding" orthographic projection (e.g. `gluOrtho2D(0, width, 0, height)`,
- and no other model view transformation,

`glRectf(0, height, 200, height-200)` creates the desired output.